# How to get SNS Subscription attributes using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sns

I am able to get the SNS subscription topics using boto (python2.7)and below code, but unable to find function to get attributes for it. How can we get the subscription attributes for SNS Subscription using subscription ARN?

```
Subscriptions=sns_conn.get_all_subscriptions()
a[0]=Subscriptions['ListSubscriptionsResponse']['ListSubscriptionsResult']['Subscriptions'][0]['SubscriptionArn']
```

Comment: It looks like you're using boto2.  Have you considered using boto3?  It has a get_subscription_attributes() method. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.get_subscription_attributes

Comment: I have to run the script using python 2.7, cann't upgrade it to python3. That is the reason I'm using boto2

Comment: boto3 runs fine under Python 2.7 as well.

Comment: I can give a try but, complete script is in boto2. need to modify everything to work with boto3 now. which real issue.

Comment: You could use boto2 and boto3 in the same script (e.g. don't rewrite the boto2 parts, but add in some boto3).  But to try and answer your question in boto2, which subscription attributes are you looking for exactly?  Some of them are available in the object returned in your above code sample (e.g. replace `SubscriptionArn` with `Endpoint`, `Owner`, or `Protocol`, etc.)  But I don't think all attributes available in boto3 are supported by boto2, as it has been deprecated.

Comment: @Fishizzle  I've modified SNS part to work with boto3 and able to run successfully. Thanks alot